# I get no matching function for call to and more

Tags: c++

I just finished with OOP section of C++ (i studied about it online) and I started a simple project. But i get some errors that I don't understand.
I have divided the project in class1.h/.cpp and class2.h/.cpp and main to be easier to read and understand.

The errors that i get are(some of them says about mingw):

```
In function 'void add_movie(Movies&, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, int)':error: no matching function for call to 'Movies::add_movie(std::__cxx11::string&)'
     if(movies.add_movie(name)){

note: candidate: bool Movies::add_movie(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, int)
     bool add_movie(std::string name, std::string rating, int watched);

error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' and 'int')
         if(movie.get_name() == 0){

note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> bool std::operator==(const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&)
     operator==(const istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>& __a,
```

Here is the code of main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Movies.h"

void increment_watched(Movies &movies, std::string name);
void add_movie(Movies &movies, std::string name, std::string rating, int watched);

void increment_watched(Movies &movies, std::string name)
{
    if(movies.increment_watched(name)){
        std::cout << name << " watch incremented!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << name << " not found!" << std::endl;
    }
}

void add_movie(Movies &movies, std::string name, std::string rating, int watched)
{
    if(movies.add_movie(name)){
        std::cout << name << " was added!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << name << " already exists!" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    Movies my_movies;
    my_movies.display();

    add_movie(my_movies, "Legacies", "G", 100);
    add_movie(my_movies, "Dark Knight", "PG", 6);
    add_movie(my_movies, "We are Millers", "PG-13", 23);
    my_movies.display();

    add_movie(my_movies, "We are Millers", "PG-13", 23);
    add_movie(my_movies, "Ice Age", "PG", 12);
    my_movies.display();

    increment_watched(my_movies, "Legacies");
    increment_watched(my_movies, "Ice Age");
    my_movies.display();
    increment_watched(my_movies, "XXX");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code for Movie.h

```
#ifndef _MOVIE_H_
    #define _MOVIE_H_

    #include <string>

    class Movie {
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::string rating;
        int watched;

    public:
        Movie(std::string name, std::string rating, int watched);
        Movie(const Movie &source);
        ~Movie();

        void set_name(std::string name)
        {
            this->name = name;
        }

        std::string get_name() const
        {
            return name;
        }

        void set_rating(std::string rating)
        {
            this->rating = rating;
        }

        std::string get_rating() const
        {
            return rating;
        }

        void set_watched(int watched)
        {
            this->watched = watched;
        }

        int get_watched() const
        {
            return watched;
        }

        void increment_watched()
        {
            ++watched;
        }

        void display() const;
    };



    #endif //_MOVIE_H_
```

Here is the code for Movie.cpp

```
#include "Movie.h"
#include <iostream>

Movie::Movie(std::string name, std::string rating, int watched)
        : name(name), rating(rating), watched(watched){

}

Movie::Movie(const Movie &source)
        :Movie(source.name, source.rating, source.watched){

}

Movie::~Movie() {

}

void Movie::display() const{
    std::cout << "Movie's name: " << name << " ,rating: " << rating << " and watched for: " << watched << " times!" << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the code for Movies.h

```
#ifndef _MOVIES_H_
#define _MOVIES_H_

#include "Movie.h"
#include <vector>

class Movies {
private:
    std::vector<Movie> movies;

public:
    Movies();
    ~Movies();

    bool add_movie(std::string name, std::string rating, int watched);
    bool increment_watched(std::string name);
    void display() const;
};


#endif //_MOVIES_H_
```

Here is the code for Movies.cpp

```
#include "Movies.h"
#include <iostream>

Movies::Movies() {

}

Movies::~Movies() {

}

bool Movies::add_movie(std::string name, std::string rating, int watched)
{
    for(const Movie &movie: movies){
        if(movie.get_name() == 0){
            return false;
        }
        Movie temp{name, rating, watched};
        movies.push_back(temp);
        return true;
        }

}


bool Movies::increment_watched(std::string name)
{
    for(Movie &movie: Movies){
        if(Movie.get_name == name){
            Movie.incremed_watched();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

void Movies::display() const
{
    if(movies.size() == 0){
        std::cout << "Sorry, no movies to show!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "===================================" << std::endl;
        for(const auto &Movie: Movies)
            Movie.display();
        std::cout << "===================================" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your header `movies.h` is not the right header. And, it would be easier for others to copy and paste if you put it all in one file.

Comment: Your first error is pretty descriptive, but I understand how it can be overwhelming to a beginner. It is saying that in your function `void add_movie(Movies &movies, std::string name, std::string rating, int watched)` you attempt to call a member function of `Movies` with a signature `Movies::add_movie(std::string&)`. Your `Movies` class does not have a member function with that signature. Do you want the option of adding a movie only by name to your `Movies` object?

Comment: The second error message also says exactly what's wrong, once you learn to decode it: There is no `==` operator defined that can compare a string (which is what `movie.get_name()` returns) and 0.

Comment: @John I want to add a movie by it's name, but with it's rating and that watched (counter of views).

Comment: @lakeweb I couldn't understand what you were saying when you said `movies.h` is not the right header, then I finally realized. My brain was replacing every instance of `Movie` under the header `Movies.h` with `Movies`.

Comment: @SkinnyFatBoy please see lakeweb's comment. The code you posted above for `Movies.h` is actually for `Movie.h`.

Comment: You are calling to a function `movies.add_movie(name)` (1 string parameter) but you have only defined `add_movie(Movies &movies, std::string name, std::string rating, int watched)` (3 parameters). Maybe the best you can do right now is to start again from the beginning, and every time you add a feature to your code, compile it, in that way you will catch more easily where the errors are.

Comment: @John I edited the code for Movies.h

Comment: @SkinnyFatBoy if you want `Movies` to have a function called `add_movie` that only takes a single string, you need to write it. It's up to you what that function does. In C++ you can have multiple functions with the same name, but that take different numbers and/or types of parameters. So you could have both `add_movie(std::string&)` and `add_movie(std::string name, std::string rating, int watched)`. If you want to call the latter function, you need to pass in a `rating` and a `watched`. Otherwise the compiler doesn't know what function to call.